# Oracle dynamic sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Why this code doesn output result?  Write PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. and that all

```
declare 
  count_train    number(20); 
  v_query_str varchar2(255);
 begin 
  v_query_str :=  'select count(*) from TRAIN';
  execute immediate  v_query_str
  into count_train;
  Dbms_output.put_line(count_train);
 end;
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql` tag for Oracle questions.

Comment: did you set serveroutput on ?

Comment: Thanks... i forgot set active this. 
That work now. Very big thanks. You can write your answer in answer field and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @kaserr The identification of the solution makes this question a duplicate of an earlier question that is deserving of an upvote of the accepted answer.

Comment: @JeffHolt  a okay, i apologies... i dont know this at that moment.